# number of ways to stack n distinct objects into k distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics

I know that number of ways to distribute $n$ distinct objects into $k$ distinct boxes is $k^n$, but there order of objects in a box doesn't matter.
If we want to stack objects in a box, then order also matters. I can't figure out how to solve this.
How can we calculate this ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can line up n objects in $n!$ ways. Now, consider a line up of the objects, and place dividers between them. Then, stack according to which order they appear in the line up.

Comment: Ok, so from stars and bars, we can place k-1 dividers in $^{n+k-1}C_{n-1}$ ways, and then multiply it by n! ?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the number of partitions of the set $N$ with cardinality $n$ into at most $k$ parts. We can use stirling coefficients of the second kind to rewrite as: $$\sum_{i=0}^k {n\brace i}$$